# Handling Azure SQL errors

Tags: sql-server, go, azure-sql

I have a function that is designed to handle TSQL queries. Essentially, it attempts to create a connection to the server, run the query, commit and then close the connection. Currently, we're relying on the [mssqldb driver](http://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) as the backend is Azure SQL.

```
func (requester *Requester) doTransaction(ctx context.Context, isolation sql.IsolationLevel, 
    txFunc func(*sql.Tx) error) error {

    // First, attempt to get a connection from the connection pool. If this fails return an error
    conn, err := requester.conn.Conn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Conn failed, Error type: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(err))
        log.Printf("Conn failed, error: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    // Before we continue on, ensure that the connection is clsoed and returned to the connection pool
    defer func() {
        if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Close failed, error: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    // Next, start the transaction with the given context and the default isolation
    tx, err := conn.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: isolation, ReadOnly: false})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("BeginTx failed, Error type: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(err))
        log.Printf("BeginTx failed, error: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    // Now, ensure that the transaction is either rolled back or committed before
    // the function ends
    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            panic(p)
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Printf("An error occurred: %v", err)
            if err := tx.Rollback(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Rollback failed, error: %v", err)
            }
        } else {
            if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Commit failed, error: %v", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    // Finally, run the function and return the result
    err = txFunc(tx)
    return err
}
```

This works well for the most part. However, I've noticed a number of errors that occur due to things like timeouts, serverless pausing, IO limits being exceeded, etc; such as:

```
Login error: mssql: Database 'my-db' on server 'myserver.database.windows.net' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{SOME_GUID}'.
```

I'd like to handle these with a backoff of some kind rather than just failing. However, to do that I need to be able to interpret the error in some fashion. However, the errors returned all have the type of `*errors.errorString`. I've tried doing using `As(error, interface{})` to check if the error was a `mssql.Error` and it's not so I'm not really sure how to handle it. How do I determine what the cause is for these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the error that you get to an Error as defined here [as defined here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#Error) using a type assertion

```
err:=//your operation that returns an error
//check and convert the error to a MSSQL error with more context
if msSQLErr,ok:=err.(mssql.Error);ok{
   if msSQLErr.SQLErrorNumber() == someRetryableErrorCode{
      //custom retry logic...
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the errors.As as follows

```
var msSQLErr mssql.Error
if errors.As(err,&msSQLErr){
   if msSQLErr.SQLErrorNumber() == someRetryableErrorCode{
      //custom retry logic...
   }
}
```

**Update**: Unfortunately, it seems like the library doesn't wrap underlying errors, so you can not use errors.Is or errors.As for some errors e.g. network related errors, so you will have to match the error strings yourself using something like strings.Contains

Comment: I tried using `errors.As` but it returned false

Comment: @Woody1193 updated the post, but basically you will need to string match some of the errors as the library doesn't wrap them using fmt.Errorf with %w verb

Comment: I was really hoping someone would tell me I was dumb rather than telling me that I'll have to do it this way

Comment: @Woody1193 you can always contribute to the project to help others and to improve the library with your use cases. You can follow this PR https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/pull/418

Comment: Also, if you look at Microsoft's example of how to accomplish PHP connection resiliency (I KNOW it's not Go, but that's what they offer along with .NET) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-4-connect-resiliently-to-sql-with-php?view=sql-server-ver15, you'll see a list of transient error codes in the example, which you can use to help inform _whatever_ approach you land on.